# This notebook was not authored by Google message on fooocus?

Tags: debugging, driver, nvidia

Warning: This notebook was not authored by Google
This notebook is being loaded from GitHub. It may request access to your data stored with Google, or read data and credentials from other sessions. Please review the source code before executing this notebook.

I also have the 1 month plan.I am running with public on an MSI with a GTX 1050 Nvidia with all driver updated

I have this message

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygit2==1.12.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pygit2==1.12.2) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.9.1->pygit2==1.12.2) (2.21)
/content
fatal: destination path 'Fooocus' already exists and is not an empty directory.
/content/Fooocus
Already up-to-date
Update succeeded.
[System ARGV] ['entry_with_update.py', '--share']
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
Fooocus version: 2.2.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/Fooocus/entry_with_update.py", line 46, in <module>
    from launch import *
  File "/content/Fooocus/launch.py", line 127, in <module>
    from webui import *
  File "/content/Fooocus/webui.py", line 10, in <module>
    import modules.async_worker as worker
  File "/content/Fooocus/modules/async_worker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from modules.patch import PatchSettings, patch_settings, patch_all
  File "/content/Fooocus/modules/patch.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ldm_patched.modules.model_base
  File "/content/Fooocus/ldm_patched/modules/model_base.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ldm_patched.ldm.modules.diffusionmodules.openaimodel import UNetModel, Timestep
  File "/content/Fooocus/ldm_patched/ldm/modules/diffusionmodules/openaimodel.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..attention import SpatialTransformer, SpatialVideoTransformer, default
  File "/content/Fooocus/ldm_patched/ldm/modules/attention.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sub_quadratic_attention import efficient_dot_product_attention
  File "/content/Fooocus/ldm_patched/ldm/modules/sub_quadratic_attention.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ldm_patched.modules import model_management
  File "/content/Fooocus/ldm_patched/modules/model_management.py", line 121, in <module>
    total_vram = get_total_memory(get_torch_device()) / (1024 * 1024)
  File "/content/Fooocus/ldm_patched/modules/model_management.py", line 90, in get_torch_device
    return torch.device(torch.cuda.current_device())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 787, in current_device
    _lazy_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 302, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

I need to create images